# Assign a variable the result of dynamic function call in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamic

In JavaScript I can assign a value to a variable by dynamically creating a function. Such as

```
var name = (function () { name="bob"; return name; }());
```

I'm fairly certain that with C# 4.0 the same type of thing is possible. Could someone show me the syntax of how the same line above would look in C#?

Also, if you could jog my memory on what the proper term for creating this type of dynamic function is, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your help!

PS: It's likely this question has been asked before, but since I was unclear on the nomenclature I may have missed finding it. If that's the case, I apologize!

Comment: In your example, you're assigning the function itself.  Not the value the function returns.

Comment: oops, thanks! If I changed it to  function() { name="bob"; return name; }(); would it work as expected?

Answer (score 6):

You can use anonymous methods:

```
Func<string> anonymousFunction = () => { string name = "bob"; return name; };
string myName = anonymousFunction();
```

The syntax on the first line is a lambda, which is the C#3.0 and above way of declaring anonymous methods. The above function takes no arguments, but there's nothing stopping you from including them as well:

```
Func<string, string> makeUppercase = x => x.ToUpper();
string upperCase = makeUppercase("lowercase");
```

Note that since there is only one parameter, you can elide the brackets around it. As well, since the entire method is a single return statement, you can elide both the brace brackets as well as the `return` statement itself.

This type of lambda is very common when using the LINQ extension methods, since many of them require a single-argument method that returns a value:

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var divisibleByTwo = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0);
```

To answer your actual question, that syntax is not valid in C#. If you try this:

```
string output = (x => x.ToUpper())("lowercase");
```

You'll get an error message saying "Method name expected." You have to assign the anonymous method to a delegate first.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Out of curiosity, is there a way to declare the anonymous function in the assignment, instead of on the line above. The reason I ask is I'd like to be able use the concept to  assign a value to a defulat property of a class during assignment (something like stu = new student() { name = ()=>(string name = "bob"; return name; } ).

Comment: Oh disregard my last comment, you updated your answer with the answer while I was typing :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you want to look into are Func/Actions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

And for that matter, lambda expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx